# CakePHP Relationship Issue

Tags: php, cakephp, relational-database

Basically, im trying to learn the basics of cakephp and im stuck at sorting the relationships out. I have tried loads of ways with no success.

I have a lead table which needs to connect to the contact table, there can be many leads to one contact. Im not sure how to do this, could someone please help?

lead model:

```
<?php
class Lead extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Lead';
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Contact' => array(
            'className' => 'Contact',
            'foreignKey' => 'contact_id'
        )   
    );
}
?>
```

contact

```
<?php
class Contact extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Contact';
    var $hasMany = array(
        'Lead' => array(
            'className' => 'Lead',
            'foreignKey' => 'contact_id'
        )
    );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since once contact can have many leads, you'll want to add

```
var $hasMany = 'Lead';
```

to your User class.

And since I assume that Lead has a foreign key referencing the 'owning' User, you'll want to add

```
var $belongsTo = 'User';
```

to your Lead class.

This will let you access leads and users from both sides of the relationship (from the lead perspective, and from the user perspective).

See the docs for [hasMany](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1043/hasMany) and [belongsTo](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1042/belongsTo) for more info.

Comment: thanks i have added that now. what would be the required field names in the database, at the minute in the lead table i have contact_id and in the contact table they key is called id, is that correct?

Comment: Check out CakePHP's database conventions that you should follow:
http://book.cakephp.org/view/903/Model-and-Database-Conventions